# Does a Core Data model "style" question belong on Code Review StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I'm about to ask a question about my Core Data model. I plan to show my model/relationships and then describe my app. Where does this question belong?

Comment: Is it code or just a model?

Comment: It's a Core Data model.

Comment: I would suggest you post on SO and if you don't get enough suitable answers, you could post on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338700/help-with-first-core-data-project) on Stack Overflow. I got some good feedback.